# evaluating imaginary integral

Tags: calculus

Im trying to evaluate the following integral:

$\int \frac{e^{ix(1-n)}}{i(1-n)} dx$ which can be written as $\int e^{ix(1-n)} dx$ 
and struggling to find the answer

My current attempt is, integral by substitution, let $u = ix(1-n)$:

Therefore $ du = i(1-n) dx$

Then, $ \frac{1}{i(1-n)} \int \frac{e^{u}}{i(1-n)} du$

Then, $ \frac {-1}{(1-n)^2} e^{ix(1-n)}$

However, using computation tools such as WolframAlpha, the answer should be:

$ \frac {-1}{i(1-n)} e^{ix(1-n)}$

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your computation is perfect, perhaps you might have missed  $i(1-n)$ in the denominator while typing in WA

Comment: Exactly, I can't find any flaws in your calculations too.

Comment: alternatively, the integral im trying to find could be expressed as $ \int e^{ix(1-n)} dx$

Answer (score 0):

When i typed the integral as, $$\int\frac{e^{i(1-n)x}}{i(n-1)}dx$$ WA showed the output as,
[image]

The integral can be equivalently written as , $$\int\frac{-ie^{(1-n)x}}{(n-1)}dx$$ as $\frac{1}{i} = -i$. With this integral WA showed the result as
[image]

Comment: hmm, when i put it into WA i get this: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5E(ix(1-n))+%2F++(i(1-n))+from+0+to+pi

Comment: ignore the 0 to Pi for now, im referring to the indefinite integral..

Comment: Cancel the $i$in Numerator and denominator in the definite integral, and the indefinite integral done by you is correct